# Bundles and dylib lookups

Tags: macos, bundle, dylib

My .app packages looks like this:

```
MyApp.app/
    Contents/
        MacOS/
            MyApp
            libA.dylib
            libB.dylib
            libC.dylib
        PlugIns/
            PlugIn1.bundle/
                ...bundle contents
            PlugIn2.bundle/
                ...bundle contents
```

Both PlugIn1.bundle and PlugIn2.bundle are linked against libA.dylib, libB.dylib, and libC.dylib.  The three dylibs have install names of @loader_path/libName.dylib.  The bundles, however, cannot find libA.dylib, libB.dylib, or libC.dylib.  I've tried setting the -bundle_loader flag to link against the main executable, but that didn't help.  Is it possible for the bundles to look up the dylibs from the MacOS folder of the .app package and not have to copy them into the bundle as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this working, I had to change the install name to @executable_path/libName.dylib

Comment: Exactly. If you read the manpage dyld (1), it should explain why: loader_path is the path to the binary that contains the load command (PlugIn1); executable_path is the path to the main executable for the process (MyApp). In most cases, it's obvious which one is appropriate—loader_path/../../../MacOS/libName.dylib is much more complicated and fragile than executable_path/libName.dylib. (When neither one seems simple enough, look into -rpath.) (Sorry for leaving out the at symbols, but I don't know how to escape them in comments…)